# Negative Correlation between phylogenetic PCA and nonphylogenetic PCA

Tags: r, pca, phylogeny

I am studying the evolution of male and female plumage coloration in a bird family, and I have been concerned that my phylogenetic PCA is broken. Since the PCA needs to be calibrated to the phylogeny, I split up male and female plumage into different datasets. I compared the scores of a nonphylogenetic PCA (using princomp, cor = TRUE) and a phylogenetic PCA (method= lambda, mode = Corr). The same log-transformed dataset was used for both types of PCA. Is there a difference in how these two methods standardize the scores? Has anyone ever experienced this before?

Additionally, within the phylogenetic PCA male plumage evolves under the lambda model, and female evolves under BM. I would seriously appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a topic other than computer coding.

Comment: Hi Ben, if you are using the package phyl.pca, maybe this might give you a clue? http://blog.phytools.org/2017/03/loadings-in-phylpca-vs-loadings-in.html

Comment: Unless you provide the code and reproducible example of how you obtained your results, it's not easy to tell how differently the pca is performed

Comment: I Ben, its probably best that you go through the phylogenetic PCA discussions in the R-Sig-Phylo archive, and if your question is not answered there, post a question to the mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-phylo@r-project.org/